# Rollup a List of data the most efficient way using java

Tags: java, database, postgresql

I have a List of data like this.

```
start: 1455262571155, seconds: 40, name: "quant1"
start: 1455263331610, seconds: 120, name: "quant2"
start: 1455263331610, seconds: 120, name: "quant2"
start: 1455263331610, seconds: 120, name: "quant3"
```

the list will go on and on. it always has a timestamp when a sensor came online and how long it lasts. You seem a value is not unique and can appear the same time. Also the same time, another value can appear.

Now I want to retransfer these data into such a format.

```
time: 12:50, value: "quant1", amount: 1
time: 12:51, value: "quant2", amount: 2
time: 12:52, value: "quant2", amount: 1
```

(Given that the start timestamps would represent 12:50...)

Now I see different problems as the algorithm needs to check if there are already values for the given timestamp. What's the most efficient way to do this in Java?

These data are stored within a PostgreSQL database.

Comment: May we know whence is the source of the JSON data?  The operation you are trying to do is really suited well for a database rather than Java.  If you need to do in Java, you can look into GSON or Simple JSON which can convert the input JSON into an object.

Comment: Sorry, the source IS in fact a database. It's actually not json, that was just for making it not more complicated as it needs to be.
So imagine, the data you are seeing above are in a relational database.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: You want a time-based windowing function on a RDBMS? That isn't very Java specific at all

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Postgres newest version and cricket_007 I simply need to rollup these data periodically as it would be too much data if I wouldn't

Comment: Do you want to keep the long value?

Comment: no. as shown in the 2. pseudocode, the "new table" should group the values to minutes

Comment: I'm just asking because storing seconds since epoch as a time format is more preferred over a HH:mm timestamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along these lines will give you what you want:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + (start / 1000) * INTERVAL '1 second', 'HH:MI') AS time,
    name AS value, COUNT(*) AS amount
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + (start / 1000) * INTERVAL '1 second', 'HH:MI'),
    name
```

The complexity here is in converting seconds since epoch to a `TIMESTAMP`, and then converting that timestamp into `HH:MI` format.

The code

```
TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + (start / 1000) * INTERVAL '1 second'
```

converts your `start` field, in milliseconds, into a `TIMESTAMP` type.  The division by `1000` is necessary to convert milliseconds into seconds.  The `TO_CHAR()` function converts that timestamp into the `HH:MI` format you want.

Comment: Yeah... Like I said in the comments, Java really has nothing to do with the question

Comment: I actually pointed that out first, but credit to you as well :-)

Comment: Ah, I missed that between the JSON comment :)

Comment: well. thank you, but this is throwing an error:
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WITH"
LINE 1: SELECT TO_CHAR(TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE 'epoch' + start * INTE...
                               ^
********** Fehler **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "WITH"
SQL Status:42601
Zeichen:24

Comment: @Christian Please try it again.  I removed the `TIME ZONE` clause which seemed to be causing problems.

Comment: ok, now it says "can't find TIMESTAMP". But the column definetly is named "TIMESTAMP". I've replaced yourTable with my table name... Still it says can't find. is it a problem because of the uppercase? Postgres doesn't seem to like this. Even if I do something like select "SECONDS" from sensors, I need to put SECONDS in "

Comment: `TIMESTAMP` is reserved by Postgres and it refers to a type.  Have you actually named one of your columns `"Timestamp"`?  I believe my query should run without error.

Comment: Oh well, thanks for explanation. Now it throws this error: [0A000] ERROR: cross-database references are not implemented: cern.sensor.seconds

Comment: Ok, I got it. But it doesn't show a timescale like 12:00, 12:01 and so an, it only shows the start time 12:00.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103265/discussion-between-tim-biegeleisen-and-christian).

Comment: We were able to resolve the problem which was due his actual data being stored as seconds in the table, not milliseconds.  But the answer given here correctly answers the OP as stated above.

Comment: Ladys and Gentlenerds, Mr @TimBiegeleisen is super awesome!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry for getting back to this, but I've seen the solution is not quit working. The example above contains the field "seconds". You've created a statement that groups *only* by starttime, but actually thats not correct. E.g. if a value has start time 12:50, it is in the bucket for 12:00. Thats correct.. But if it has more than 600 seconds, it also needs to be in the bucket of 13:00. Is this kind of complicate logic even possible with pure sql?

Comment: Please email me at TimBeagle@hotmail.com ... I am sure that what you want is achievable.